# Updating MXDs with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, mxd

I am trying to loop through a bunch of mxds in a folder and make some changes, in this case in particular I am trying to replace a text string. This should change all instances of "9/26/2014" with the dynamic date tag. The code runs fine but when I open one of the mxds, the date is not updated. Is there some saving or refreshing that has to be done that i'm not doing currently?

```
import os
import sys
import string

folderPath = '[folder path goes here]'
sort_list=[]
oldText = "9/26/2014"
newText = "<dyn type='date' format='short'/>"

for filename_1 in os.listdir(folderPath):  
    sort_list.append(filename_1) #append to empty list
    list_length = len(sort_list)  #list length for progress
sort_list.sort() #sort

for filename in sort_list:      
  fullpath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename) 

  if os.path.isfile(fullpath):   #check if its a file
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fullpath)  #split into the name and extension
    if extension.lower() == ".mxd":  #if its an ArcGIS document
      mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)
      print mxd
      df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]
      print df

      #Find all page layout text elements
      for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        if oldText in elm.text:
          print(oldText)
          elmText = elm.text.replace(oldText, newText)
          elm.text = elmText
          print(elmText)                          
          arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
          mxd.save

          arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem might be a very simple typo in this case, no big deal at all. The code posted in your question is providing a [reference to the callable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785933/purpose-of-calling-function-without-brackets-python) with the name `mxd.save`, it doesn't appear to be actually executing the save [method](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/mapdocument-class.htm#M1_GUID-CCD917AA-83A1-497A-AE17-2665B62CAC34) onboard the `mxd` object. The original code here will pass through silently without error, which is indeed frustrating/confusing in this case.

Replacing `mxd.save` with `mxd.save()` should fix it.

Comment: That was it! Thanks! I know I originally have the parentheses but lost them somewhere along the way.